# Basis and Span of Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm revising Linear Algebra. Currently, I'm going through basis and dimension. We know that a basis is a set that spans the vector space and the vectors in the set are linearly independent.

My question is whether a single-element set that spans a space can be the basis for the vector space.

Comment: This is in fact exactly what it means for a vector space to be one-dimensional.

Comment: Is your question  "what does linear independence mean if there is only one vector in the set?"

Comment: No. I knew a single set element of a vector space is linearly independent.

Comment: "*We know that a basis is a set that (1) spans the vector space and the vectors in the set are (2) linearly independent*"  The single-element set that spans the space does in fact... (1) *span the space* as required, and is in fact (2) *linearly independent*, so... it satisfies both properties.  What is the question again?

Comment: I just needed a clarity. I got through the answer by Believer and the comment by Malady. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, why not.
Consider vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
It has $\{1\}$ as a basis.